# Replace object in nested array

Tags: arrays, dictionary, filter

guys, I know this is not a hard task but I struggle with it for almost 2 days.
I have next array of properties which contains a single property which also contains an array of votes object.
And from front i got object with vote 1 or 0 and user that send it. How I can replace the nested object in an array with that object I got from a client?

Comment: Please tag with the language your are using.

Comment: javascript but already solved that issue)thanks)